# Calculate Cron Next Run Time in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, cron

I have crontab-like scheduler. Time definition "MM HH WD MD M":

MM- minutes
 HH- hours
 WD- days of week
 MD - days of month
 M - months

WD, MD and M allow multiple entries and each of params can be null, for example:

```
^ ^  0, 1  ^ ^      means exucution every minute, every hour, at sunday and mondey, every day<br>

35 15 ^ ^ ^    execution every day at 15.35<br>
```

The problem is how to calculate next run time, if you know last execution date. I know how to do this using loop (just add 1 minute until it fits the condition), but there must be better way.

Comment: I hope you aren't underestimating the job. If you really want to be (POSIX) cron compatible you'll [have to cater for a _lot more than that_](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/crontab.html) (I know, I've implemented that once in C++)

Comment: @kol: I guess he needs <strike>Noda Time</strike> **edit** a _lot of time_.... :)

Comment: If it's `MM HH` first, then wouldn't `15 35` throw an exception?

Comment: `if you know last execution date` - erm... the last execution has nothing to do with crontab specs (they are absolute time references)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've successfully used [NCrontab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/) for exactly this purpose.

using something like

```
var schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse("15 35 * * *");
return schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Cool! But one question. If, for example, SomeDate is execution time   GetNextOccurence(SomeDate) will return SomeDate?

Comment: Pretty sure it will return the next occurence, but GetNextOccurrences(startTime, endTime) will return IEnumerable<DateTime> of all the occurences in that range. :)

Comment: "0 0 12 ? * MON-FRI * " Fails the above Condition. is there any Solution

Answer (score 6):

[Cronos](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos) is another excellent option for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can either code that yourself using [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) and [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) - for example:

```
DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours (15).AddMinutes (35)
```

checks whether it is 15:35 currently (and thus some execution needs to take place),  similar checks can be implemented for day of week, day of month etc.

*or use a really nice opensource .NET library* called [NodaTime](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) (is definitely a better way).

Another option is to use a different architecture - for such scheduler type apps/services there is an opensource .NET library called [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) (is even better) which does among these calculations lots of other very useful things in this context.